# ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: No such attribute (16)

Tags: ldap, openldap, sasl

I am getting the error while running ldapsearch command and client side authentication also not coming.

Could anyone please help me to sort out the problem ?

ERROR MESSAGE

> ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: No such attribute (16)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you intent using `SASL`? In not use `-x` to use simple authentication.

Comment: THanks YSU but we solved the issue

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `-x` switch uses simple authentication instead of of the default SASL. So use something like this:

`ldapsearch -x -h 192.268.0.78 -p 389 cn=root,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com`

Comment: Wow, well this fixed my problem, but why?? My ldapsearch call involves neither authentication nor encryption :-?